# Do not URI encode when using httparty

Tags: ruby, httparty

I have a request setup using httparty and would like to not have URI encoding take place. I have read that there is a class method available

```
query_string_normalizer proc { |query|
  query.map do |key, value|
    value.map {|v| "#{key}=#{v}"}
  end.join('&')
}
```

But I  am unsure of how to use this in my current setup

```
url = 'https://url/here/report.json?'
query = { 'param1' => '125894',
          'param2' => 'yesterday',
          'param3' => 'about',
          'param4' => 'client',
          'parameters' => 'ns_ti:*',
          'user' => ENV['USERNAME'],
          'password' => ENV['PASSWORD']
}
response = HTTParty.get(url, query: query)
results = JSON.parse(response.body)
```

The issue here is that `parameters` gets encoded and gets sent as 'ns_ti%3A%2A' and I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make  your own wrapper for HTTParty and pass a proc to the normalizer that overrides the URI encoding.

```
app/config/intializers/rich_lewis_http.rb
```

.

```
class RichLewisHttp

  include HTTParty

  query_string_normalizer proc { |query|
    query.map do |key, value|
      [value].flatten.map {|v| "#{key}=#{v}"}.join('&')
    end.join('&')
  }

end
```

Then you can do...

```
response = RichLewisHttp.get(url, query: query)
results = JSON.parse(response.body)
```

Comment: seem to be getting `undefined method map for "125894":String`

Comment: any ideas on this one?

Comment: Ah, right... it looks like the code is designed to handle value being an array... the edit I've made to the answer should fix it.

Comment: Thank you for your help again, much appreciated

Comment: Wonderful, thanks @SteveTurczyn! I had a query parameter with an unescaped **single** backslash in it, and HTTParty's default `query_string_normalizer` was escaping it and sending the escaped string (**double** backslash).